# Form Required Doesn't Work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have tested three ways of doing a field required, first with no gem, just the usual `form_for` and it did work well, but I need some good gem for making easier adding fields to insert associations, then I installed the Simple Form. Here is the code I am using:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |p| %>
<%= p.text_field :title, :required => true %> <br />
<%= p.input :content, required: true%> <br />
<%= p.input :category_id, input_html: { required: true }%>
<%= p.submit %>
<% end %>
```

See how I used all the three ways of getting required to true and the usual way of creating a text field of the `form_for` so I can see if I find a solution. No success. Even after making `config.browser_validations = true` in `config/initializers/simple_form.rb`. Why is it working for `form_for` but not when I am using gems? I also tried Formtastic and had the same issue.

Comment: After adding `config.browser_validations = true`, did you restart the server?

Comment: Yep, @ArslanAli

Comment: Do you have  a presence validation for your model?

Comment: Could you please share the generated HTML with us?

Answer (score 0):

If you place required: true in the input you should see the field has the "required" class and `required="required`" attribute.